# Is it possible to have different alignments for list items within a navbar menu?

Tags: css, menu, navigation, bulma

I have a responsive collapsing navbar menu done in CSS. I'm using the bulma CSS framework to construct my page.

I am trying to have a logo permanently displayed on the left, with the menu list items horizontally centered. I would use the same technique to align the logo left as to align a searchbox on the right.

This is my attempt so far:

```css
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    margin: 0em;
    color: rgb(19, 51, 61);
}

p {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    max-width: 55em;
}

p a {
    color: rgb(41, 183, 206);
    text-decoration: none;
}

strong {
    color: rgb(41, 183, 206);
}

nav {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: rgb(19, 51, 61);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(19, 51, 61, 0.5);
    padding: 0 1em;
    height: 44px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

nav img {
    text-align: left;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    max-height: 88px;
    position: relative;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1em;
    color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 44px;
    height: 44px;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
}

nav li:last-child { 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0;
    bottom: 44px; 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(19, 51, 61, 0) 0, rgba(19, 51, 61, 1) 2em);
    padding-left: 3em;
}

nav li:nth-last-child(2) { 
    display: none;
}

nav#menu:target {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

nav#menu:target ul {
    max-height: none;
}

nav#menu:target li {
    display: block;
}

nav#menu:target a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 2em;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}

nav#menu:target a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
}

nav#menu:target li:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 2px;
}

nav#menu:target li:last-child {
    display: none;
}

nav#menu:target li:nth-last-child(2) {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-left: 2px solid rgb(19, 51, 61);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.2/css/bulma.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<nav id="menu">
    <ul id="menu-closed">
        <li><img src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/971caf673b2a29c7b6d6af6c74b9d7e649214eb1765bfef0848b68d3ce3a40fb/68747470733a2f2f63646e2e737667706f726e2e636f6d2f6c6f676f732f766974656a732e737667" style="max-height: 44px;"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu-closed">&#215; Close menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu">&#9776; Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I've tried various things, as well as some of bulmas positioning classes, and I can't seem to get it to stick to the left no matter what I do.

What is the correct approach here?

Bonus question: How can I maintain the list elements being vertically centered as they are if the image is removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your logo to an absolute position on the left and add equivalent same paddings to the menu list on the left and right.

```css
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    margin: 0em;
    color: rgb(19, 51, 61);
}

p {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    max-width: 55em;
}

p a {
    color: rgb(41, 183, 206);
    text-decoration: none;
}

strong {
    color: rgb(41, 183, 206);
}

nav {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: rgb(19, 51, 61);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(19, 51, 61, 0.5);
    padding: 0 1em;
    height: 44px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

nav img {
    text-align: left;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    max-height: 88px;
    position: relative;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1em;
    color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 44px;
    height: 44px;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
}

nav li:last-child { 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0;
    bottom: 44px; 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(19, 51, 61, 0) 0, rgba(19, 51, 61, 1) 2em);
    padding-left: 3em;
}

nav li:nth-last-child(2) { 
    display: none;
}

nav#menu:target {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

nav#menu:target ul {
    max-height: none;
}

nav#menu:target li {
    display: block;
}

nav#menu:target a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 2em;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}

nav#menu:target a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
}

nav#menu:target li:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 2px;
}

nav#menu:target li:last-child {
    display: none;
}

nav#menu:target li:nth-last-child(2) {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-left: 2px solid rgb(19, 51, 61);
}

nav#menu > ul {
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.2/css/bulma.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<nav id="menu">
    <ul id="menu-closed">
        <li class="logo"><img src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/971caf673b2a29c7b6d6af6c74b9d7e649214eb1765bfef0848b68d3ce3a40fb/68747470733a2f2f63646e2e737667706f726e2e636f6d2f6c6f676f732f766974656a732e737667" style="max-height: 44px;"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu-closed">&#215; Close menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu">&#9776; Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: That works very well, thank you. Should have known it was so simple. Would you also know how to vertically center the logo? I'm using a slightly different logo while playing with the design and it is set at the top

Comment: `top: 10px;` or whatever number will be enough to center it. `margin-top: 10px;` should work also. `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%)` - should also work. You can also rewrite all your code to flex with equal width blocks on left (logo) and right (search) and just use `align-items: center;`. There are a lot ways to achieve what you want, I'd suggest you dive deeper in CSS and learn how it works :)

Comment: Ah, I've been trying to dive into CSS for years now, it's just not my main area I work in, I work in security. But, I'm continuing to get it. Thanks very much for your help :)